# JUnit Assertion error expected and actual showing the same thing

Tags: java, junit

My expected and actual in my Assertionerror are showing the same thing. And they are the same reference. Anyone know why and how to fix? Code and error below. Thanks in advance:

```
@Test
public void test_CreateAUserWritesAFileReadsFilePrintsFile() throws IOException {
    //Arrange
    WriteCommand fwc = new FileWriteCommand();
    ReadCommand frc = new FileReadCommand();
    RegistrationController rc = new RegistrationController();
    User user = new User("Jerry", "123", "Engineer");
    rc.registerNewUser("Jerry", "123", "Engineer");
    fwc.writeUser(user);
    User one = frc.readUser("Jerry");
    System.out.println(one);
    User expected = one;

    //Act
    User actual = user;

    //Assert
    assertEquals(expected, actual);

}
```

Error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: com.fdmgroup.userregistration.User<User [username=Jerry, password=123, role=Engineer]> but was: com.fdmgroup.userregistration.User<User [username=Jerry, password=123, role=Engineer]>
```

Comment: Probably your equals() implementation within the user class has a different understanding of equality then you..

Comment: The user 'user' and the user 'one' are different objects. Try to print the user objects.

Comment: In other words : read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly by adding details about the User class.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `User user = new User("Jerry", "123", "Engineer");` is creating a new User object and `User one = frc.readUser("Jerry");` is also creating a new User object. these two objects' field values are same but these two objects are different. However you can assert that by doing this.

```
assertThat(user).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(one);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields have the same values, but the objects being compared are different.

Asserting equivalence between the fields of the objects should succeed, and unless I completely misunderstand what you are testing for, it's more correct.